# Why should we use next js configuration file in React project? What's the main purpose using it?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, configuration-files

I need to know about the configuration file. Why we use it to react project.

Comment: Have you had a look at [`next.config.js` documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/introduction)?

Answer (score 0):

- with next.js, you can write your environment variables in ".env.local" but those environment variables will be for server-side. if you want to add environment variables for your client, you add it to next.config.js
- If you want to add a new webpack plugin
- If you want to convert your app to progresive web app

  ```
   module.exports = {
      webpack: (config) => {
        // adding a webpack pugin
         config.plugins.push(new MonacoWebpackPlugin());
        return config;
      },
      // this will pass the env variable to the client side
      env: {
        AUTH0_NAMESPACE: process.env.AUTH0_NAMESPACE,
        BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL,
        EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID: process.env.EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID,
        EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID: process.env.EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID,
        EMAILJS_USER_ID: process.env.EMAILJS_USER_ID,
        BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL,

      },
      // set up for progressive app
       pwa: {
        dest: "public",
        // runtimeCaching,
        swSrc: "service-worker.js",
      },

    };
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add configuration file in next js project for custom advanced behavior of Next.js. The file next.config.js is a regular Node.js module, not a JSON file. It gets used by the Next.js server and build phases, and it's not included in the browser build